# How to access the action method data in the remix?

Tags: shopify, remix, remix.run

I made a GraphQL call from the action method and got the URL in the response. In the action, I want to redirect that URL but I am not able to get the window object in the action method that's why I am trying to use the useActionData method. But the problem is I am not able to get the URL on the first click. I got the URL after second time when I had to click the button. Below is my code.

```
export async function action({request}){
  const { admin, session } = await authenticate.admin(request);
  const shop = await session.shop;
  const graphql = await admin.graphql;
  const data = Object.fromEntries(await request.formData())

  const plan_50kg = await db.plans.findUnique({ where: { id: 4 } });

  const shopName = await shop.split('.')[0];
  const appName  = process.env.APP_NAME;
  const args_50kg = {
    "name":"Super Duper Capped Pricing Plan",
    "return_url": "https://admin.shopify.com/store/"+shopName+"/apps/"+appName+"/app",
    "terms": "$"+plan_50kg?.usage_charges+" USD every 30 days",
    "cappedAmount": {
      "amount": ""+plan_50kg?.capped_amount+"",
      "currencyCode": "USD" 
    },
    "price": {
      "amount": ""+plan_50kg?.price+"",
      "currencyCode": "USD"
    }
  }
  const confirmation_url_50kg = await createSubscription(args_50kg, graphql);
  
  
  return json({
    confirmation_url: confirmation_url_50kg,  
  });
}


const Pricing = () => {
  const data = useActionData();
    <Form method="post">
      <input type="hidden" value="1" name="plan_id"></input>
        <input type="hidden" name="plan_id"></input>
           <Button submit primary onClick={()=>{
                    console.log("data", data);
                  }}>Unsubscribe</Button>
     </Form>
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To redirect from inside your action, use the `redirect` method.

```js
import { redirect } from "@remix-run/node";

export async function action({request}){
  // ...
  const confirmation_url_50kg = await createSubscription(args_50kg, graphql);
  
  return redirect(confirmation_url_50kg);
}
```

https://remix.run/docs/en/main/utils/redirect